# Why do I get NullPointerException when my Integer[] has already been initialized?

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception

I was trying to make a code to answer to another person's problem... and I came out with another problem.

The idea would be a program that asks you to input numbers so it sorts them and prints them out from higher to lower.

This is what I came with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input: ");
    Integer input = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()));
    scanner.close();
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[input.toString().length()];

    for (Integer value : numbers) {
        while (input > 1) {
            value = input % 10;
            input /= 10;
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());

    int a = 0;
    for (Integer value : numbers) {
        if (a < numbers.toString().length()) {
            System.out.print(value + ", ");
            a++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(value + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

But, being `Input: 292816374` the input, this is what the console says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at StartingPoint.main(StartingPoint.java:21)
```

The problem is that it is trying to sort `null` integers, but I don't know why it detects `numbers` as a null array when it's already been initialized.
If I change the `Integer`s to `int`s there aren't exceptions, but it prints out zeroes.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It can't be a duplicate because I did initialize the array.

Comment: you are iterating number using forecah but you have assigned length to input[] (good part) an your number[] is empty(bad part)

Comment: The problem was due to that I was trying to assign each `numbers`'s field by refference and not by explicitly mentioning them.
That's why `numbers` was empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created the array with

```
Integer[] numbers = new Integer[input.toString().length()];
```

`Integer` is an object type, so all the values in the array start off as null. If it were `int`, then it would be an array of primitives, which would all be initialized to 0.

As you want to update the array value try

```
 for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {

      numbers [x] = value; // whatever
 }
```

Comment: In that line of code what I'm doing is setting `numbers`s size.
I initialize it in the enhanced `for` loop.

Comment: @JavaNoob you don´t initialize them in the `for` loop. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: "You can not iterate through values which do not exist" You CAN.  You are simply iterating thru an array with `null`s, so `value` is simply `null` for each iteration.  Of course the original logic is still flawed, but your explanation is wrong.  And even OP has initialized the array with `Integer` instances, his way to populate data by the loop is still wrong and do not give correct result.

Comment: @ScaryWombat So my problem is due to that I'm trying to assign each `numbers`'s field by reference and not doing this by mentioning each one of them. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianShum Yes, I did not explain that well.

Comment: @JavaNoob remember that `Integer`s are immutable

Comment: @ScaryWombat Situation won't change even Integer is mutable, because OP is doing `value = newValue;` which is simply making `value` (which is an object ref) referring a new object.

Comment: @AdrianShum Thanks, explanations are not coming easy today.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Integer value : numbers) {
    while (input > 1) {
        value = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
}
```

`value = input % 10;` is not doing what you are expecting: it will NOT set the value in the array.  It is just like:

```
Integer i = numbers[0];  // assuming numbers[0] is 0 at this moment
i = 100;
// numbers[0] is STILL 0
```

You have to assign value to the array explicitly.

A suggestion to do what you want is something like:

```
int i = 0;
while (input > 0) {
    numbers[i++] = (input % 10);
    input /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created the array but you didn't assigned values to the array.

In your enhanced `for` loop you are assigning the value to the `value` variable which will store nothing in the array, you need to do it manually to store the value to array.

Try the below code:

```
int index = 0;
for (Integer value : numbers) {
    while (input > 1) {
        value = input % 10;
        input /= 10;

        // assigning value back to numbers array
        numbers[index] = value;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That'd solve my problem by assigning the refference variable `value`'s value to each `numbers`'s field.
It is even shorter if I just use a normal `for` loop and assign each `numbers`'s field directly, though.

Comment: Normal for and assigning it numbers array directly will definitely shorter the code, but here in my answer I used your code, so that you can easily understand what you are missing.. :)

Comment: Exactly. I just pointed it out in case that a person with the same problem were seeing this; your answer is great.